# Compare two files using first column, print diff while appending column to output

Tags: bash, unix, awk, diff

I have two tab-delimited files that I want to compare.

I want to look for values of col1 in file1 that are missing in file2 (prepend with "left") and values in col1 in file2 that are missing in file1 (prepend with "joined"). For these lines, I want to print col1 and col8. My diff command fails for lines with an equal col1 and different values for col8.

file1:

```
Char1   55  Necromancer Knight  A   11/21/21    Zone    Char1(Main)     off off 0       Char1(Main) 
Char2   28  Druid   Squire  A   12/08/21    Zone    Char1       off off 0       Char1   
Char3   44  Enchanter   Recruit A   08/07/21    Zone    Char3(Main)     off off 0       Char3(Main) 
Char4   56  Enchanter   Knight  A   11/06/21    Zone    Char4(Main)     off off 0       Char4(Main) 
Char5   10  Magician    Recruit A   10/29/21    Zone    Char1       off off 0       Char1   
Char6   65  Druid   Champion    A   12/12/21    The Lair of the Splitpaw    Char6(Main) VT emp time     off off 0       Char6(Main) VT emp time
```

file2:

```
Char1   55  Necromancer Knight  A   11/21/21    Zone    Char1(Main)     off off 0       Char1(Main) 
Char2   28  Druid   Squire  A   12/08/21    Zone    Char1       off off 0       Char1   
Char3   44  Enchanter   Recruit A   08/07/21    Zone    Char3(Main)     off off 0       Char3(Main) 
Char4   56  Enchanter   Knight  A   11/06/21    Zone    Char4(Main)     off off 0       Char4(Main) 
Char5a  10  Magician    Recruit A   10/29/21    Zone    Char1       off off 0       Char1   
Char6   65  Druid   Champion    A   12/21/21    Zone    Char6(Main) Emp/VT/Time     off off 0       Char6(Main) Emp/VT/Time
```

diff command producing output:

```
diff --new-line-format="joined %L" --old-line-format="left %L" --unchanged-line-format="" <(cut -f1,8 "$file1" | sort) <(cut -f1,8 "$file2" | sort) | sort
```

Current output:

```
joined Char5a   Char1
joined Char6    Char6(Main) Emp/VT/Time
left Char5      Char1
left Char6      Char6(Main) VT emp time
```

Desired output:

```
joined Char5a   Char1
left Char5      Char1
```

Any help is greatly appreciated, thank you!

Comment: what's the question? is the current output wrong? does the current output need to displayed in a different format?  please update the question with 2 sample input files, only the code necessary to perform the desired processing (eg, do we really need to know about how you find the 2 files to process?), the (wrong) output generated by your code and the (correct) expected output

Comment: I thought the "question" was clear in the last two lines of running the function. It's detecting a change for the second column when I don't want it to do that, but still want it printed.

Comment: @Jedis After reading your question a couple of times, I think I understand it. It is always difficult to make a question completely clear, so having two input files with 2 columns and 6 lines each, and the result you want, would help.
Perhaps rephrase your question, something like `I want to look for values of col1 in file1 missing in file2 (prepend with "left") and values in col1 in file2 missing in file1. For these lines I want to print col1 and col8. My diff command fails for lines with equal col1 and different values for col8.

Comment: @WalterA Thank you. I have edited my post to reword it and make it more clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Diff is for simple differences. A solution for your problem is easier with `awk`.
You do not need to sort the files, just read both files and count how often the keys in column 1 occur.
While counting the key values prepare the potential output. When `NR==FNR` you are in the first file and you want to use "left".
When both files are read, look for keys with only one occurance and print the prepared output for that line.

```
awk -F'\t' '
  {
    key[$1]++
    value[$1]=(NR==FNR ? "left " : "joined ") $1 "\t" $8
  }
  END { 
    for (i in key) { 
      if (key[i]==1) { 
        print value[i]
      }
    }
  }' file1 file2
```

Comment: Thank you. I had to add -F'\t' to tell it that I was working with a tab delimited file, otherwise it was throwing odd, inconsistent output, with columns and some lines not having data in every column. Will keep testing it a bit more.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this python script gets what you are expecting :

```
#!/bin/bash

python -c '
import re, sys
def read_into_dict(regex, file):
    return { re.findall(regex, line)[0]: line for line in open(file) }
regex, file1, file2 = sys.argv[1:]
dict1 = read_into_dict(regex, file1)
dict2 = read_into_dict(regex, file2)
keys1 = set(dict1.keys())
keys2 = set(dict2.keys())
for key in (keys1 - keys2):
    print(f"left {dict1[key]}")
for key in (keys2 - keys1):
    print(f"joined {dict2[key]}")
' '^(\S+)' <(cut -f1,8 "$file1" | sort) <(cut -f1,8 "$file2" | sort) | sort
```